# Script to run a command at 10 o'clock

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I would like to know how I could run a script that will run a command on my PC if the time is equal to x. I have heard of the `at` command and some others but I'm trying to make mine a bit unique.

The problem is when I try my script, when my computer is on and I run it, it checks the hour but if I turn my PC on at x:36 or something, then my refresh will occur at an hour after x but with 36 minutes, advice please!

**My script**

```
time="$(date +%H)"
echo $time
if [ $time != "22" ]; then
    sleep 1h
else
    zenity --title="asdf" --text="asdf" --info
fi
```

Comment: Read up on cron/at but why reinvent the wheel

Comment: Thanks, crontab was exactly what i needed :) thanks to other answers too!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to sleep 1 hour, you want to sleep *until* 2200. With GNU `date`, you can use

```
now=$(date +%s)
t=$(date +%s --date 2200)
sleep "$now"
zenity --title="asdf" --text="asdf" --info
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the command at 22:00 only, output and compare both hours and minutes:

```
time=$(date +%H:%M)
if [ $time != 22:00 ] ; then
    sleep 58
...
```

Comment: `sleep 60` isn't guaranteed to sleep _exactly_ 60 seconds -- it could sleep more, it could sleep less. Risking missing the window on a heavily-loaded system doesn't seem ideal.